# Eclipse Job: How to override Job's error handling dialog

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jobs

I had a requirement to disable 'Run In Background' button from Progress monitor while Job is running. After I searched in forums, I did not find any direct solution to do so. Thus, I am using Workbench's progressive service to run the job and creating the Job in non-UI user mode(setUser(false)) as shown below.

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getProgressService().run(true, true, new IRunnableWithProgress() {
            @Override
            public void run(final IProgressMonitor progressMonitor) throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {
    progressMonitor.beginTask("Start Job", 1);
         Job job = new Job("Job1") {

            @Override
            protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor dummyMonitor) {
                //Use monitor of progressive service
                progressMonitor.beginTask("Started Job1", no_of_tasks);
                //Perform Job and update monitor once task is done
            }
            @Override
            public boolean belongsTo(Object family) {
                return family == BuildConstants.MY_JOB_FAMILY;
            }
         });
     }
    job.setUser(false);
    job.schedule();
    //Wait for Job to be done
    IJobManager jobManager = Job.getJobManager();
    Job[] jobs = jobManager.find(BuildConstants.MY_JOB_FAMILY);

    while(jobs.length > 0) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //Do nothing.
        }
        jobs = jobManager.find(BuildConstants.MY_JOB_FAMILY);
    }
    //Once job finishes exit the Progressive service. 
});
}
```

With this approach all positive scenarios are working fine. But in case of error, Job is showing 'Problem Occured' dialog and it is closing immediately, as the progressive service is exiting once the job is done(as job manager does not find any job belong to family 'MY_JOB_FAMILY').

Note: I can not perform all my tasks directly in IRunnableWithProgress, as I am running multiple Jobs in parallel from a parent Job.

My questions are as below:

1. Is there a different approach to disable 'Run In Background' button of Job ?
2. Is there a way to stop the 'Problem Occured' dialog to appear ?
3. How could I make my progressive service to wait for user click on 'problem occured' dialog ?

Comment: Why use a `Job` at all? Why not just run the code in the `IRunnableWithProgress`

Comment: Hi Greg-449,

I am running multiple parallel Jobs.